# Float 5 Different Size Boxes In Order And Make Fill Wrapper With CSS

Tags: html, css, css-float, wrapper

**I'm trying to float 5 boxes in a specific order, as shown in this first diagram.**  All boxes are the same size except one which is the same height as 2 boxes + the space between them (but this seems to be the killer):

[image: Desired Layout]

Key points here are:

A: Each of the 5 'boxes' is a div element, and crucially has a border drawn by CSS (we'll shortly see this causes issues with padding/margins)

B: Red Circle 1 - Image three cannot be the exact correct height but I still need the bottom border of Box 3 to be exactly in line with the bottom border of Box 2

**My HTML is:**

```
<div class="hpcategorypagewrapper">
    <div class="hpcategorytopwrapper">
        <div class="hpcategorytopleftwrapper">
            <div class="hpcategory">
                <h1 class="hpcategory">Title One</h1>
                <h3 class="hpcategory">Subtitle One<br /><img src="/image1.jpg" /></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="hpcategoryspacer"> </div>
            <div class="hpcategory">
                <h1 class="hpcategory">Title Two</h1>
                <h3 class="hpcategory">Subtitle Two<br /><img src="/image2.jpg" /></h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="hpcategorytoprightwrapper">
            <div class="hpcategory">
                <h1 class="hpcategory">Title Three</h1>
                <h3 class="hpcategory">Subtitle Three<br /><img src="/image3.jpg" /></h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="hpcategoryspacer"> </div>
    <div class="hpcategorybottomwrapper">
        <div class="hpcategoryleft">
            <h1 class="hpcategory">Title Four</h1>
            <h3 class="hpcategory">Subtitle Four<br /><img src="/image4.jpg" /></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="hpcategoryright">
            <h1 class="hpcategory">Title Five</h1>
            <h3 class="hpcategory">Subtitle Five<br /><img src="/image5.jpg" /></h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I think I need the HTML in this order because I will use different CSS to show the boxes in the following order for mobile devices (but don't worry about this CSS, it should be easy):

[image: mobile layout]

**The CSS** I am using to try and achieve the layout I showed in image ONE **is supposed to create the following sized divs** (artistic licence taken on drawing all the div boxes so they can be seen - in reality these lines would be on top not next to each other):

[image: div structure]

**The CSS code I wrote to do this is:**

```
h1.hpcategory { font-size: 45px; color: #00bfff; text-align: center; font-weight: 700; margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 0; padding-bottom: 0; line-height: 0.8em; }
h3.hpcategory { font-size: 30px; color: #00bfff; text-align: center; font-weight: 600; margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 0; padding-bottom: 0; line-height: 0.7em; }
img.hpcategory { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

div.hpcategorypagewrapper { width: 100%; }
div.hpcategorypagetopwrapper { width: 100%; height: 100%; clear: right; padding-bottom: 20px; overflow: hidden; }
div.hpcategorypagebottomwrapper { width: 100%; padding-top: 20px; }
div.hpcategorytopleftwrapper { width: 49%; float: left; }
div.hpcategorytoprightwrapper { width: 49%; height: 100%; float: right; clear: right; }
div.hpcategory { border: 3px solid #00bfff; }
div.hpcategoryleft { width: 49%; float: left; border: 3px solid #00bfff; }
div.hpcategoryright { width: 49%; float: right; border: 3px solid #00bfff; }
div.hpcategoryspacer { height: 25px; width: 100%; clear: right; }
```

**However the layout comes out looking like this:**

[image: main problems]

**The problems are:**

Red Circle 2: Box Three has not extended down to the bottom of Box 2.  Further, Box Four has been placed where Box 3 should have extended to.
No matter how I try and force the height of either 'hpcategorypagetopwrapper' or 'hpcategorytoprightwrapper' to 100%, it won't obey.
I tried adding 'overflow: hidden' in all intuitive places in CSS from a stackoverflow solution but that hasn't helped.

Red Circle 3: There is no horizontal spacer between row 2 of boxes and row 3 (e.g between box 4 and 5).  This is strange as the same technique did successfully create a spacer between Box 1 and Box 2.

In an attempt to try and resolve Red Circle 2 (Box 3 won't take 100% of its wrapper's height) I created an image almost exactly the right height to force bottom border of box 3 to be in line with bottom border of box 2.  This isn't perfect and they don't line up properly so **I can't use this for the final, but the result is better:**

[image: newer problems]

**The newer problems are:**

Red Circle 4: Image 3 can never be exact right height as different browsers are rendering different gaps between text (especially on mobile) and so bottom borders of Box 2 & 3 don't line up.

Red Circle 5: For some crazy crazy reason the horizontal gap between Box 4 and 5 is significantly smaller than between Box 1/2 and Box 3.  I can't work out why given Box 1, 3, 4 and 5 are all set at 49% width.  I tried inserting

```
margin-left: 0; margin-right: 0; padding-left: 0; padding-right: 0;
```

into the CSS for all the div elements to ensure it wasn't different margins/padding messing this up and this didn't help.

How can I get this to work?

**Crucially:**

- I need box 3 to extend to exact height of bottom border of box 2 without knowing how many pixels this is (varies between browsers because of differences in rendering horizontal gaps between text).
- I want to be able to add the horizontal space between box 1 and box 2 with 'margin-bottom: 30px' in the CSS (instead of the ridiculous spacer div I've currently created), but because of the box borders this does not work - the margin ends up on the INSIDE of the border instead of the outside!
- I need the vertical spacing between Box 4 and Box 5 to be the same as between Box 1/2 and Box 3.

Please help me with CSS and HTML - I don't know any JS so won't be able to use a solution involving that.

I've spent ages on this and I'd really appreciate your help. My HTML and CSS knowledge is 10 years old and very outdated but I need to put together a website for a new business I'm starting so I've done my best to learn divs and 'html5' vs the good old tables and TR and TDs I used to love, but I've hit a brick wall...

Comment: Unfortunately, you are setting yourself up for a world of pain by desiring a layout like that. Even if you start to use fixed heights, positioning etc. you might get your desired result in one browser and not in another. This is where graphic design doesn't translate well to the web.

Comment: I really appreciate your reply.  But it looks so simple! What is the crucial thing going wrong here?

Comment: Sounds like this could be done with Bootstrap's columns ..

Comment: It's tricky to deal with matching heights in CSS—especially where text is involved. Each browser displays text slightly differently, so for a start you are in trouble when relying on text height. Then the end user can increase font sizes, and your layout blows apart. The web is a fluid medium and isn't well sited to fixity.

Comment: Bit why cant I just set my top right container to be the same height sa the top left container? This confuses me no end. A table with tr and td would easily achieve this...

Comment: Ralph - what about 'red circle 5' - can I at least solve that and put up with bottom border of box 3 not being exactly in line with box 2?

Comment: Hm, I've had a look and to get the columns is fairly easy (using Bootstrap,) but the 3rd being a matching height to 1st + 2nd is not.

Comment: I don't see a way for the 3rd container to always match the bottom of the 2nd container without involving either some basic JS/JQ or weird and hacky CSS. Or wrapping them all in the wrapper with a fixed height, but ix pixels used you can't have the images reponsive, so consider using %.

Comment: Anyway, I'm going to stop trying. Here's what I've done in case anybody else wants to play with it: http://jsfiddle.net/Uyzak/1/ problem is that it only works in Chrome :P Uses Bootstrap. Sorry this isn't more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Is this the general idea you have in mind? [**My Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/asapmmeehan/Uyzak/2/)

I have a few more thoughts, but I just want to see if I have you on the right track.

```
.block {
    width:48%;
    float:left;
    margin:1%;
    background:#ccc;
}
.wrap-three {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    float:left;
}
.block-one {
    height:46%;
    float:left;
   margin-bottom:3%;
}
.block-two {
    height:46%;
   margin-top:3%;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
}
.block-three {
    height:300px;
}
```

Comment: BTW, is the image in #3 exactly twice the size of the images in #1 and #2 in every case? Either way we have some options.  We can make this work I think?

Comment: It is set to be responsive at 520px for this example.

Comment: Michael this looks really good! Sorry for the late reply, I'm in the uk so just grabbed my 6 hours of sleep. To answer your question the image on #3 would ideally be exactly twice the size of the images in #1/2 + the margin between box 1/2. Because different browsers are renderimg different gaps between title one and subtitle one and same for t2/st2 I will then have to subtract a few pixels to ensure the image isn't too tall (or set box 3 to cut the image off if it would push bottom border of box 3 below box 2).

Comment: One tricky thing may be adding borders to each box. I found that 'margin' would add the margin inside the border rather than outside, thus pushing the borders of all boxes right next to each other.  Would love to play woth your jsfiddle so far (and figure out exactly what that site is) but need to run to a meeting for a few hours. Thanks so much for all yoir help so far. David

Comment: These can be overcome! You desire to have the page load in the HTML in the correct semantic order is paramount.  If you add a border,  try to reduce the width by using a single decimal the %, ie. 46.7%.  This works back I believe to IE8.  As for images it can useful to place them in a container and use CSS to manipulate the desired block image anyway you want. When it comes to Browsers, and a manipulation such as this I try to keep in mind the end user is only going to see it in one browser.  So the tweaking for each can be done.